# The integral $\int_{0}^\pi\frac{d\omega}{(2\sin(\omega/2))^{2\alpha}+2\lambda(2\sin(\omega/2))^\alpha\sin(\alpha\omega/2)+\lambda^2} $?

Tags: special-functions

Can the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^\pi\frac{d\omega}{(2\sin(\omega/2))^{2\alpha}+2\lambda(2\sin(\omega/2))^\alpha\sin(\alpha\omega/2)+\lambda^2},\quad 0<\alpha<2,\quad \lambda>0
\end{equation}
be evaluated?

At first thought, I tried to write $\sin(\alpha\omega/2)$ as function of $\sin(\omega/2)$ such that a variable replacement $t=\sin(\omega/2)$ can be done. However, it seems no such relation exists.

Could you give me some ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the Weierstraß substitution might help?

Comment: A question out of curiousity: So far, all your problems have had a common theme of generalizing certain results to include a parameter $0<\alpha<2$. Is there an underlying motivation to them?

Comment: Yeah, It's part of a problem involving fractional order calculus.